# Building balanced BST from sorted array: recursive and iterative approaches

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-search

I am implementing an algorithm to solve the following problem:

> Given a sorted (increasing order) array with unique integer elements, write an algorithm to create a binary search tree with minimal height.

The solution of this problem using recursion is quite straightforward:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def build_bst_recursive(array):
    size = len(array)
    return _build_bst(array, first=0, last=size - 1)


def _build_bst(array, first, last):
    if last < first:
        return None
    mid = (first + last) // 2
    node = Node(mid)
    node.left = _build_bst(array, first, mid - 1)
    node.right = _build_bst(array, mid + 1, last)
    return node
```

Out of curiosity I also would like to solve the same problem using an iterative algorithm. Here is what I came up with:

```
class Stack:
    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
            self.next_node = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.head_node = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head_node is None

    def push(self, value):
        node = self._Node(value)
        node.next_node = self.head_node
        self.head_node = node

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception("Stack is empty.")
        node = self.head_node
        self.head_node = node.next_node
        return node.value

def build_bst_iterative(array):
    size = len(array)

    # Stack stores tuples of the first and the last indices of half-segments:
    stack_indices = Stack()
    stack_indices.push((0, size - 1))

    # Stack stores tree nodes:
    stack_nodes = Stack()

    # Add to the stack a node that will be a root of the tree:
    root_node = Node(None)
    stack_nodes.push(root_node)

    while not stack_indices.is_empty():
        first, last = stack_indices.pop()
        node = stack_nodes.pop()

        if last < first:
            # The segment is degenerated. Keep the node empty.
            continue
        elif last == first:
            # Assign the value, it is the last bottom node.
            node.value = array[last]
            continue

        mid = (first + last) // 2
        node.value = array[mid]
        node.left = Node(None)
        node.right = Node(None)

        # Update stacks:
        # (right half-segment)
        stack_indices.push((mid + 1, last))
        stack_nodes.push(node.right)
        # (left half-segment)
        stack_indices.push((first, mid - 1))
        stack_nodes.push(node.left)
    assert stack_nodes.is_empty()

    return root_node
```

I would highly appreciate if you could review the code and suggest any approaches for improvement. For example, I am trying to understand if it is possible to use only one stack.

**EDIT** After looking into my code in the morning, I realise that there is no need for two stacks because I always push and pop to the two stacks at the same time. Here there is an updated version of the code:

```
def build_bst_iterative_one_stack(array):
    size = len(array)

    # Add to the stack a node that will be a root of the tree:
    root_node = Node(None)

    # Stack stores tuples of the current node, and the first and the last indices of half-segments:
    stack = Stack()
    stack.push((root_node, 0, size - 1))

    while not stack.is_empty():
        node, first, last = stack.pop()

        if last < first:
            # The segment is degenerated. Do nothing.
            continue
        elif last == first:
            # Assign the value, it is the last bottom node.
            node.value = array[last]
            continue

        mid = (first + last) // 2
        node.value = array[mid]
        node.left = Node(None)
        node.right = Node(None)

        # Update the stack with the left and the right half-segment:
        stack.push((node.right, mid + 1, last))
        stack.push((node.left, first, mid - 1))
    assert stack.is_empty()

    return root_node
```

Comment: (The second thing striking about the iterative approach is the roll-your-own stack - what's wrong with `list.append/pop`? The sole reason I tried to understand that non-commented code was that I was curious whether you presented a bottom-up procedure.)

Comment: @greybeard thank you for your comment. You are right I could use a `list`. I also added some comments to make the iterative algorithm easier to understand. In a bottom-up procedure you would build tree from bottom? In this case I have a top-down procedure. I would highly appreciate if you could elaborate how to implement a bottom-up procedure. Also, what is also the first thing striking about the iterative approach?

Comment: (I was about to compliment you on your post when I found part of the praise would have to go to 200_success - in my eyes, you didn't do half bad as it is.) (Note that changes to the code are not welcome once reviews started.)

Comment: @greybeard (ok, probably I miss something about what 200_success wrote.) (Thanks for telling me about the code changes, I didn't know about this. Just joined the community.)

Comment: (See also: [Create Balanced Binary Search Tree from Sorted linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406975))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start with an all too common hindsight:
your code lacks test support and scaffold.

The most basic test support for a class is a succinct `__str__`, for `class Node`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '<' + ('.' if not self.left else (str(self.left) + '|')) \
        + str(self.value) + ('.' if not self.right
                             else ('|' + str(self.right))) + '>'
```

(a more elaborate one would allow to limit recursion.) The result for

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ascending = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('g'))]
    print(build_bst_recursive(ascending))
    print(build_bst_iterative_one_stack(ascending))
```

> <<.0|<.1.>>|2|<<.3.>|4|<.5.>>>
>   <<<.None.>|a|<.b.>>|c|<<.d.>|e|<.f.>>>

highlights an oversight with `_build_bst()` (not using `node = Node(array[mid])`) and a problem in the stack variants with always creating two child nodes (or with the handling commented `# The segment is degenerated. Do nothing.`).

---

Your code is more or less in line with the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) (good - do you use an IDE, your IDE's PEP8 support?); make it a habit to provide [documentation strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) for everything public, too.

If I was serious about comparing alternative implementations, I'd try to define an [interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) and hope to avoid names like `build_bst_iterative_one_stack`.
I got used to the builtin `len()`, I don't see an advantage to introducing `size = len(array)` *where used once*.

`_build_bst()` is pretty basic; if it was public, it would need a *doc string* specifying `last` to be inclusive. I don't like the name `array` - would prefer `values` or `ordered` (`ascending` would be misleading, as `_build_bst()` works perfectly for descending values).

I'd hesitate to roll my own stack class, more so if the stated purpose was something else, entirely. If I did, I'd just extend `list`:

```
class Stack(list):
    ''' syntactic sugar: adds push(), is_empty() to list's pop() '''
    push = list.append

    def is_empty(self):
        return not bool(self)
```

(Skipping `build_bst_iterative()`.)
In `build_bst_iterative_one_stack()`, I'd prefer `toDo` over `stack`. The comment `stack stores […and…] indices of half-segments` is funny in the first tuple pushed two statements down *not* being a half.
I don't have an inspiration how to fix the introduction of *`None`-Nodes* without duplicating the check.

Your "`build_bst_iterative*()`" implementations are straightforward conversions of the basic recursive approach (see [Create Balanced Binary Search Tree from Sorted linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406975) for one working without "random" access); I would not expect insights beyond *doesn't get prettier for explicit stack handling*.

Much to my dismay, I didn't find a decent web reference for a genuine iterative approach (numerous weird ones, some as new as [2019/3/2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.02499)):
First consider the case of 2ⁿ-1 nodes: with *level*s numbered from 0 for bottom (up to *n-1*), the level of each node is the number of trailing zeroes in its ordinal. Have an array to reference one node for each level, initialised to `None`s. For each value, create a `Node`. Check the reference at the level indicated by the number of trailing zeroes in its ordinal: if `None`, just plant the node there and make whatever is one level lower its left descendant. If not `None`, make node the right descendant of the node at the next higher level an set this level to `None`. (As an alternative to checking this reference, you can inspect the bit in the ordinal just two above the trailing zeroes.)
There are numerous ways to handle *N* ≠ 2ⁿ-1; one being to aim for a [complete binary tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees): compute the ordinal *rb* of the rightmost node at the bottom level. Proceed as above to *rb+1*, and increase the "ordinal number" by two instead of one thereafter.
(Finally, return the node at the highest level as the root of the tree built…)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your review! (I use PyCharm and you can configure https://github.com/ambv/black to format the code on save or on shortcut) (I also didn't yet come up with a strategy how to overcome the introduction of None-Nodes...) (Special thanks for the link that you provided about how to implement the algorithm for SLL. It is really useful to see how you can do it with in-place traversal!) (Wow I am quite surprised that I came up with a question that brings us to very recent publications in the field.) Thank you again for your time, reading your review was really useful.

Comment: @desa: on the [CR help page on asking questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking), there is one [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) - see the paragraph about *I improved my code…*. (My take on *accepting an answer* has shifted to *allow two days before accepting an answer* (the good news being that you can shift the accept to a different answer).)